# Selenium: Trouble with Java and Kotling together when using JavascriptExecitor

Tags: selenium, kotlin

I have a testing framework using Selenium and Cucumber, where (for now) most of the step definitions for the tests are written in Java. But I'm gradually converting to Kotlin, and therefore my newest "helper/util" class is written in Kotlin.

The SeleniumUtils.kt class:

```
import no.our.e2e.framework.selenium.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor

object SeleniumUtils {
  fun elementExistsOnPage(idSelector: String?): Boolean {
      return Browser.extendedDriver().findElements(By.id(idSelector)).size > 0
  }
}
```

The one simple method in the class above is usable from the Java step definition files without issue:

```
@When("^jeg go to the contakt page$")
public void goToContaktPage() throws InterruptedException {
    if (SeleniumUtils.INSTANCE.elementExistsOnPage("messageDraftLink")) {
        goToContaktPageViaMessagebox();
    } else {
        navigationPage.contakt.click();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to add a second method to the SeleniumUtils.kt class, to use JavaScriptExecutor to scroll the window up to the top, I run into problems:

```
import no.our.e2e.framework.selenium.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor

object SeleniumUtils {
  fun elementExistsOnPage(idSelector: String?): Boolean {
      return Browser.extendedDriver().findElements(By.id(idSelector)).size > 0
  }

  fun scrollPage() {
      (Browser.extendedDriver() as JavascriptExecutor)
        .executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, -document.body.scrollHeight)")
  }
}
```

When I access the scrollPage() method from a step definition file, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class 
no.our.e2e.framework.selenium.driver.ExtendedWebDriver cannot be cast to class 
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor  
(no.our.e2e.framework.selenium.driver.ExtendedWebDriver and 
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I've never seen this error before, but it seems to have to be specific for the Kotlin class in the context. Any ideas?

Comment: It's having trouble casting the type here. Usually we'd initialize as "webdriver" type. However it's really a Chromedriver, Geckodriver, etc... who all implement webdriver. Webdriver does not guarantee javascript executor method, but Chromedriver, Geckodriver (the super) does implement JavascriptExecutor which is why you can usually cast it.  Kotlin might have an issue casting the type.  You might just intialize the driver as Chromedriver, Geckodriver, etc... from the get-go.  (If you don't need to support multiple drivers with the same code.)  Extend that if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to answer my own question, but there's no need to waste anyone else's time when I've found the solution myself. I did the creation and initialization a bit more tidy:

```
val driver = Browser.extendedDriver();
var jse = Browser.vanillaDriver() as JavascriptExecutor

fun scrollPage(direction: scrollPage) {
    if (direction === scrollPage.UP) {
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-250)")
    } else if (direction === scrollPage.DOWN) {
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)")
    }
}
```